# Why do some logging calls not reach app insights?

Tags: c#, azure, logging, azure-application-insights

I have an issue where some logging calls are not reaching App Insights, but others are

I added a controller to test this

```
    public class LogController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<BankingController> _logger;
        private readonly IServiceProvider _services;

        public LogController(ILogger<LogController> logger,
            IServiceProvider services)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _services = services;
        }

        [HttpGet("test-logging")]
        public async Task TestLogging()
        {
            _logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "Test Logging controller - information manual");
            _logger.LogTrace("Test Logging controller - trace");
            _logger.LogInformation("Test Logging controller - information");
            _logger.LogWarning("Test Logging controller - warning");
            _logger.LogError("Test Logging controller - error");
            _logger.LogCritical("Test Logging controller - critical");

            var logger = _services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<LoggingController>>();
            logger.Log(LogLevel.Information, "DIRECT Test Logging controller - information manual");
            logger.LogTrace("DIRECT Test Logging controller - trace");
            logger.LogInformation("DIRECT Test Logging controller - information");
            logger.LogWarning("DIRECT Test Logging controller - warning");
            logger.LogError("DIRECT Test Logging controller - error");
            logger.LogCritical("DIRECT Test Logging controller - critical");
        }
    }
```

None of the logging calls here reach App Insights

However, in another part of the API, in program.cs we have a logging call that does reach App Insights

```
    public static class IWebHostExtensions
    {
        public static IWebHost MigrateDbContext<TContext>(this IWebHost webHost, Action<TContext,IServiceProvider> seeder) where TContext : DbContext
        {
            using (var scope = webHost.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

                var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<TContext>>();

                var context = services.GetService<TContext>();

                try
                {
                    logger.LogInformation($"Migrating database associated with context {typeof(TContext).Name}");

                    var retry = Policy.Handle<SqlException>()
                         .WaitAndRetry(new TimeSpan[]
                         {
                             TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3),
                             TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                             TimeSpan.FromSeconds(8),
                         });

                    retry.Execute(() =>
                    {
                        //if the sql server container is not created on run docker compose this
                        //migration can't fail for network related exception. The retry options for DbContext only 
                        //apply to transient exceptions.

                        context.Database.Migrate();
                    });
                  

                    logger.LogInformation($"Migrated database associated with context {typeof(TContext).Name}");
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    logger.LogError(ex, $"An error occurred while migrating the database used on context {typeof(TContext).Name}");
                }
            }

            return webHost;
        }
    }
```

[image: These work]

Has anyone ever come across this?

I tried a totally fresh App Insights instance

As you can see, the method used for logger uses ServiceProvider like the approach that works for migrations

I really need the normal ILogger convention to work reliably

Im using .NET Core 3.1

In my startup.cs I have

```
 services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();
```

I have tried changing the logging levels in my appsettings and still my custom messages are not being logged

```
"Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Trace",
        "Microsoft": "Trace",
        "System": "Trace"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "System": "Warning"
    }
  },
```

Paul

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using the right type for ILogger? In your code I can see you're using BankingController as the Type but on a different class. Try this:

from:

```
public class LogController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly ILogger<BankingController> _logger;
```

to:

```
public class LogController : ControllerBase
{
     private readonly ILogger<LogController > _logger;
```

Comment: Sorry I missed that when I was typing the question my actual controller is called bank controller

Comment: I have corrected the question

Comment: Any other ideas?  I cant figure this out at all